# Curl PUT is not working as expected for updating branch protection on github

Tags: curl, github, github-api, put

I have created a temporary repository named `testingProtectedBranch` found [here](https://github.com/kasunsiyambalapitiya/testingProtectedBranch) for testing the creation of `protected branches` in `github` by using `curl`. 
Here is the command I used for the purpose,but it is not working. I tried to find the error for about 2 hours but still I couldn't find it. Can anyone help me to find what is wrong in this command. Thanks in advance

```
curl -X PUT -H "Accept:application/vnd.github.loki-preview+json" -d '{"required_status_checks": {"include_admins": true,"strict": true,"contexts": ["continuous-integration/travis-ci"]},"required_pull_request_reviews": {"include_admins": false},"restrictions": {"users": ["octocat"],"teams": ["justice-league"]}}' https://api.github.com/repos/kasunsiyambalapitiya/testingProtectedBranch/branches/master/protection
```

**Update with -vv**

- Trying 192.30.253.117...
- Connected to api.github.com (192.30.253.117) port 443 (#0)
- found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
- found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
- server certificate verification OK
- server certificate status verification SKIPPED
- common name: *.github.com (matched)
- server certificate expiration date OK
- server certificate activation date OK
- certificate public key: RSA
- certificate version: #3
- subject: C=US,ST=California,L=San Francisco,O=GitHub\, Inc.,CN=*.github.com
- start date: Tue, 08 Apr 2014 00:00:00 GMT
- expire date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 12:00:00 GMT
- issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
- compression: NULL
- ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1

  ```
   PUT /repos/kasunsiyambalapitiya/testingProtectedBranch/branches/master/protection HTTP/1.1
   Host: api.github.com
   User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
   Accept:application/vnd.github.loki-preview+json
   Content-Length: 217
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  ```

  - upload completely sent off: 217 out of 217 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    < Server: GitHub.com
    < Date: Wed, 11 Jan 2017 12:45:54 GMT
    < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    < Content-Length: 87
    < Status: 404 Not Found
    < X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
    < X-RateLimit-Remaining: 58
    < X-RateLimit-Reset: 1484141537
    < X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.loki-preview; format=json
    < Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
    < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    < Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
    < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
    < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    < X-Frame-Options: deny
    < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    < X-GitHub-Request-Id: CB5E5F06:772E:59404EA:58762901
    < 
    {
    "message": "Not Found",
    "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
    }
  - Connection #0 to host api.github.com left intact

Comment: Do you get any error message? Try to add the `-vv` parameter, that gets more debug info from curl.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten sorry for the delay, it didnot allow me to edit and post it again. had to do little formating. The output with -vv is updated in the question, can you please help me to find the problem